# What are other theories of causality besides graphical models and Bayesian networks?

Tags: lo.logic, graph-theory

I am trying to find some data structures/mathemetical theories to represent causal relationships which differ from graphical models or Bayesian Networks. Any ideas?

Comment: There may be some usefule information found at an earlier question (which generated quite a bit of debate): http://mathoverflow.net/questions/22490/correlation-and-causation-when-can-we-believe-correlation-reasonably-at-least

Comment: I would say that most of it can be cast in terms of adapted filtrations.

Answer (score 4):

The standard account of causality is Lewis's theory of counterfactuals. He wrote a small, very readable book called [*Counterfactuals*](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=pwA1r9WFraoC&dq=lewis+counterfactuals&printsec=frontcover&source=bn&hl=en&ei=nDMXTKjsIt2V4gbj8JmtDA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q&f=false), which [the SEP summarizes here](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/causation-counterfactual/). The idea is to take the viewpoint of modal logic, and interpret the counterfactual conditional $A \;\boxdot\!\!\!\to B$ (read "if A were the case, then B would be the case") as holding if $B$ holds in the nearest world in which $A$ holds. Obviously this requires enriching modal logic with a notion of similarity of worlds, as well.

A lot of other people have worked on this subject; personally I am most fond of [McCain-Turner causality](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.42.1611), since Graham White has given it a [nice proof-theoretic formulation](http://en.scientificcommons.org/26422902).

Comment: I wouldn't say there's a single standard account of causality. For a discussion of further accounts - mechanistic, probabilistic, agency - try http://www.kent.ac.uk/secl/philosophy/jw/2004/causality.pdf.

Comment: That's a fair point -- I meant "standard" in the sense of "the one everyone feels obliged to argue with", rather than "the one everyone accepts".

Answer (score 2):

With several variables connected by asymmetric causal relations, it's not so likely that a mathematical theory of causality will escape graphical representation. Neel mentioned above Lewis's counterfactual analysis, and this has a close affinity with aspects of Judea Pearl's work on casual Bayesian networks, see p. 239 of http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=wnGU_TsW3BQC.

Among quantitative approaches, a variant on the usual statistical approach is Janzing and Schoelkopf's use of algorithmic dependence to determine causal relations: http://www.kyb.mpg.de/publications/attachments/paper_IEEE_version3_webseite_6526%5B1%5D.pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Burks, A.W. (1977), *Chance, Cause, Reason : An Inquiry into the Nature of Scientific Evidence*, University of Chicago Press, Chicago, IL.